# setting up primary and foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i've tried to set the primary and foreign key using the method that i learn at http://fellowtuts.com/php/setting-up-foreign-key-in-phpmyadmin/ but an error came up stating that

`#1025 - Error on rename of '.\sistem_akaun\#sql-1b70_7d' to '.\sistem_akaun\detail_akaun' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)`

can i know what's the problem here?sorry if this question sounds stupid,just a newbie

Comment: Post the structure of your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it easier to specify a foreign key manually, in SQL.

```
ALTER TABLE Table
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Column) 
REFERENCES TableToReference (ColumnToReference)
```

(Where Table is the table you wish to add a foreign key to)

Comment: this error come up                                                  "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sistem_akaun`.`#sql-1b70_a3`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1b70_a3_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `maklumat_akaun` (`id`))"

Comment: Okay, that error means that you are updating a row in the main table which includes a value in the foreign key column that does not exist in the table being referenced.

Comment: So, if you have an Employees table and a Supervisors table. Lets say the Employees table has three columns - Employee_ID, Name, and Supervisor_ID, and there is a foreign key constraint on Supervisor_ID. The Supervisors table has two columns - Supervisor_ID and Name. If you add a record to Employees with a Supervisor_ID that doesn't exist in the Supervisors table, it will fail with this error. That is the very point of a foreign key constraint.

Comment: so what's the solution?or am i missing the point you talking about? @Eilidh

Comment: So if you have this foreign key, and you have two Supervisors in the Supervisors table. Supervisor_ID 1, Name Linda; and Supervisor_ID 2, Name Jakob, then every Employee record in the Employee table must have a Supervisor_ID of 1 or 2. The foreign key constraint on the Supervisor_ID column in Employees means **any value in that column in that table must already exist in the other table**. So if you tried to add an entry to the Employees table with a Supervisor_ID of 3, this would fail and throw that error, because no entry in the Supervisors table has Supervisor_ID 3. Make sense?

Comment: hey,hi so yeah i've managed to do this but now i'm adding another primary key inside the table and setting up a new foreign key in a new table using what you've said earlier but it shows error #1215 cannot add foreign key constraint, how come? @Eilidh

Comment: It could be any of a number of reasons. Make sure the two fields are the same exact type (e.g. both INT UNSIGNED, or both SMALLINT SIGNED).

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the Primary Key you are referencing exists. If, in your main table, you have id_main = 0 on your main table, where id_main is a foreign key referencing id_ref (which is the primary key of the other table) but you have reference ref_id = 1 and no 0 value, you will get an error.

Check to make sure your foreign key is the primary key of the other table.

Check to make sure they are the same data type, length, unsigned status. Sometimes these matter sometimes not.

Sometimes I've had trouble where both Foreign Key and Primary Key are both named "id". This can be a problem depending on what software/methods you are using.

Answer (score 0):

@itsfawwaz, You can also do this by below way. Check below example.

**Example : (Table Orders)**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

Above is sample example, you can use your own table fields !

Let me know if still you have any issues.

Comment: where should i apply this sql? the parent or the child table ? @PHP Weblineindia

Comment: I suggest looking at some SQL tutorials as your understanding seems pretty basic :)  SQL Zoo is excellent. 

This code is simply an example of how to **create a table** with a foreign key constraint. My answer shows how to add a foreign key constraint to an existing table.